# Firebase realtime database offline persistence in Unity

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I noticed that if I send some data to the database while internet connection is dropped, after I reconnect the data doesn't get resent. Is this feature not available for unity or am I missing something? This docs say that this should work but it doesn't : https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/unity/save-data#write_data_offline

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found out what was the issue. On Android, you need to enable external write permission in order for that feature to work, which is silly, because we do not want to enable this permission. Firebase should save its data to the perstistent data path which doesn't require any permissions.